# Changed apache httpd.conf Document Root but still showing old page

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, web-server

I'm using Centos7 and Apache for web server. 
I want to change the document root from "/var/www/html" to a folder in home directory.

I have already changed the httpd.conf file accordingly and restart apache, even reboot the system. 
But when I reload the page, it's still showing file in "/var/www/html". 
I have used grep search the whole etc/httpd folder but cannot find any lines that are using "/var/www/html". I don't know where is referring this folder.
Any idea or solution?

FYI, somehow it is listening to 888 instead of 80. When i changed to 80 with httpd.conf. I cannot start apache. 
I check that both 888 and 80 is used by apache but with different pid. Is this normal and will this be the reason?

Thank you

Comment: Hi .. Could u share your httpd.conf ?

Comment: Also share the error message that apache is howing when you try to start it....